# Error Undefined offset en PHP (Crear tabla con resultado de procedimiento almacenado)

Tags: php, html, array, cakephp

Necesito **imprimir** las ventas de los operadores de cada día, no se toman en cuenta los feriados los fines de semana. Me da el siguiente error

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 1 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 6 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 7 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 13 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 14 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]
>
> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 16 [APP/View/Reportes/getventas_asistencia.ctp, line 63]

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div style="width: 100%; ">
    <legend style="color:grey" ><?php echo __('Resultados');?></legend>
</div>

<div class="table table-bordered" style="width=100%;"  >
    <table width="100%" border="1" style="text-align:center;">
        <?php
         // $i=0;
         // $j=0;
        $columnas = count($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
        //echo $columnas;

        $filas = count($AsistenciaVentas);  
        //echo "<br>".$filas."<br>";

        //Añadimos los titulos          
       for($i=0;$i<count($AsistenciaVentas[0]);$i=$i+1){
          next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
          echo "<th><b>".key($AsistenciaVentas[0])."</b></th>";
        // next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
        }    
        for($i=0;$i<$filas;$i++){
        echo "<tbody><tr>";
        for($j=1;$j<$columnas;$j++){
        echo "<td>".$AsistenciaVentas[$i][$j]."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr></tbody> ";
        }
        ?>  
    </table>
</div>
```

El resultado del array se ve así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [usuario_id] => 1055
            [nombre_usuario] => Alejandro Espinoza Salinas
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 3
            [8] => 3
            [9] => 
            [10] => 2
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [15] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [usuario_id] => 1248
            [nombre_usuario] => Alex Rodrigo Azocar Bernal
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
            [15] => 0
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [usuario_id] => 377
            [nombre_usuario] => Alicia Escobar Cuadra
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 
            [4] => 9
            [5] => 5
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 
            [10] => 6
            [11] => 4
            [12] => 4
            [15] => 2
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [usuario_id] => 1243
            [nombre_usuario] => Barbara Andrea Soto Ramos
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 3
            [12] => 
            [15] => 1
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [usuario_id] => 1200
            [nombre_usuario] => Claudio Esteban Nunez Gajardo
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 3
            [8] => 6
            [9] => 6
            [10] => 6
            [11] => 
            [12] => 3
            [15] => 
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => 
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
        )
```

No se que hacer para eliminar los mensajes y para que me imprima los nombres de usuarios y id

---

Muchas gracias Jorge, probé de la siguiente manera:

```
if (array_key_exists(0, $AsistenciaVentas)) {for($i=0;$i<count($AsistenciaVentas[0]);$i=$i+1){
      if(!empty($AsistenciaVentas[0]))
      {
        next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
        echo "<th><b>".key($AsistenciaVentas[0])."</b></th>";
        // next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
      }
    }
```

y no me funcionó.

Resultado de lo que quiero mostrar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que muestra mi pag incluyendo los offset

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### EDITADA: GENERANDO UNA TABLA AUTOMÁTICA

Con este código podrás recorrer el array y generar una tabla automática con sus encabezados.

Ten en cuenta que no puse todo tu array por motivos de brevedad, pero si lo implementas con el array completo te generará la tabla como la presentas en la imagen.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/WNIG40227)**</kbd>

```
<?php
/* PHP: tabla automática a partir de un array asociativo - https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132129/29967  */
    $arrUsuarios=array(
                    array("usuario_id" => 1055, "nombre_usuario" => "Alejandro Espinoza Salinas", "2" => "2", "3" => "2", "4" => "2" ),    
                    array("usuario_id" => 1248, "nombre_usuario" => "Alex Rodrigo Azocar Bernal", "2" => "" , "3" => "" , "4" => "" ) 
                    );

    $strHTML= "<table>";
    /*Encabezados de la tabla*/
    foreach (array_keys($arrUsuarios[0]) as $th) {
        $strHTML .= '<th>' . $th . '</th>';
    }
    /*Filas y celdas*/
    foreach($arrUsuarios as $fila) {
        $strHTML.= "<tr>";
        foreach($fila as $celda){
            /*Si la celda está vacía, cambiamos su valor por NULL*/    
            $td=($celda) ? $celda : "NULL";
            $strHTML.= "<td>" . $td . "</td>";
        }
        $strHTML.= "</tr>";
    }
    $strHTML.="</table>";
    echo $strHTML;
?>
```

#### Resultado:

Aquí se muestra un ejemplo de resultado limitado, no reproduje el array completo por motivos de brevedad:

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>usuario_id</th>
  <th>nombre_usuario</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1055</td>
    <td>Alejandro Espinoza Salinas</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1248</td>
    <td>Alex Rodrigo Azocar Bernal</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Saludos, Los titulos después del nombre usuario varian según los días que tenga el mes por eso no puedo colocarlos fijo.

Comment: ¿Cuáles títulos @AlexandraTeran, te refieres a los valores numéricos que aparecen después? Yo leí que tú querías: *que me imprima los nombres de usuarios y id*.

Comment: Los titulos son: usuario_id, nombre_usuario y los números de los días según el mes a evaluar. cuando hago la consulta me muestra los valores pero salta los resultados y me muestra el mensaje de offset

Comment: Eso es lo que hace el código @AlexandraTeran, ¿lo has analizado, has visto los resultados debajo? El código recorre todo el array y te va imprimiendo el `usuario_id` y `nombre_usuario`. ¿No era eso lo que querías?

Comment: @AlexandraTeran prueba ahora, el código genera una tabla automática con el contenido del array.

Comment: Si lo recorre pero no imprime las variables usuario_id y nombre_usuario y las que imprime las imprime donde no debe, observa las fotos y es cuando muestra los offset.

Comment: @AlexandraTeran, ¿tú viste la tabla que hay en la respuesta? Este código crea exactamente los resultados como los tienes en la imagen. Si no es así, significa que hay algún problema en tu código, algún olvido. Si comparas el fragmento de código veras que la estructura es la misma de tu imagen. Mejor de ahí, se daña.

Comment: Si claro que la veo pero no está igual, si te fijas la columna usuario_id no aparece, la columna nombre usuario imprime solo el titulo y no los nombres y si te fijas en la fila 2 el 0 que aparece en la columna del día 22 deberia aparecer en la del 15. y así pasa con otras filas, según lo que entiendo no está encontrando algo en el recorrido y salta mostrando los mensajes. Muchas gracias por estar pendiente y responder.

Comment: @AlexandraTeran no nos estamos entendiendo. En la pregunta tú pusiste una imagen diciendo *resultado de lo que quiero mostrar*, y en mi respuesta yo reproduje parcialmente tu array y escribí un código que **hace exactamente lo que muestras en la imagen**. Si tú vas al final de mi respuesta y pulsas en el botón azul que dice **`Ejecutar`**, verás una tabla con dos filas nada más (porque no reproduje todo el array), y con las columnas y los datos exactamente como tú los quieres. Si tú aplicas ese código a tu array real, te dará una tabla completa con todos los datos bien. ¿Me explico o no?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias. ayer no me di cuenta de eso. Lo corrí y funciona correctamente. :)

Comment: @AlexandraTeran, ten en cuenta que puedes usar reglas CSS para mejorar la forma en que los datos aparecen en la tabla, pero ese sería otro tema. Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible lee:  **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos

por que no validas usando un 
if (!empty($value))?
por ejemplo algo asi en tu codigo

```
for($i=0;$i<count($AsistenciaVentas[0]);$i=$i+1){
      if(!empty($AsistenciaVentas[0]))
      {
        next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
        echo "<th><b>".key($AsistenciaVentas[0])."</b></th>";
        // next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, probé de la siguiente manera:

if (array_key_exists(0, $AsistenciaVentas)) {for($i=0;$i".key($AsistenciaVentas[0]).""; // next($AsistenciaVentas[0]); } } y no me funcionó probare como indicas. saludos. No se que es lo que debo validar exactamente para que no me muestre el mensaje

Comment: saca el next del if que puse y solo deja el echo dentro del if y el next antes del if

Comment: Lo coloque como indicas pero sigue sin funcionar : for($i=0;$i<count($AsistenciaVentas[0]);$i=$i+1){
     next($AsistenciaVentas[0]); 
  if(!empty($AsistenciaVentas[0]))
      {
        
        echo "<th><b>".key($AsistenciaVentas[0])."</b></th>";
        // next($AsistenciaVentas[0]);
      }
    Edite la pregunta con las imagenes de lo que quiero mostrar y lo que me está mostrando. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas